# Time complexity of computing homomorphic image

Tags: time-complexity, turing-machines, homomorphism

The class of regular languages $\textrm{REG}$ is closed under inverse homomorphisms. The class $\textrm{TIME}(n^k)$ of languages solvable by a one-tape TM is also closed under inverse homomorphisms for $k\geq 2$: we can replace every input symbol $a$ by $\phi(a)$ using shifting the string, this takes time $O(n^2)$, and then run the TM for the language. I am wondering if one can compute homomorphic image in time $o(n^2)$ on a one-tape TM.

For example, let us consider some language in $\textrm{TIME}(n\log n)$, for instance $L=\{0^n1^n : n\geq 0\}$ or $L=\{w\in\{0,1\}^{*} : |w|_0=|w|_1\}$.

**Question**: Is $\phi^{-1}(L)\in \textrm{TIME}(n\log n)$ for all homomorphisms $\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

This is true (for all reasonable functions, not just $n\log n$) if $\phi$ is *$\epsilon$-free*. You do not need to compute $\phi(w)$ explicitly, you just need to simulate a TM $M$ deciding $L$ on $\phi(w)$ using the original input $w=w_0\dots w_{n-1}$.

To do this, use a mixed-length encoding: let the $i$th cell of the tape represent $k_i=|\phi(w_i)|$ cells of the simulated tape (if $i$ is past the end of the original input, put e.g. $k_i=1$). Choose the representation of $k$-tuples of symbols of $M$ by symbols of the alphabet of the simulating machine such that a symbol $a$ of the input alphabet represents $\phi(a)$, so that the original input $w$ directly represents $\phi(w)$. The state of the simulating machine will record the state of the simulated machine $M$ and the simulated head position within the current $k$-tuple. In this way, each step of the computation of $M$ is simulated by one step of the simulating machine.

This does not work if $\phi(a)=\epsilon$ for some symbol $a$, because then a simulation of one step of $M$ may involve skipping over a long subword that maps to $\epsilon$, raising the overall time bound by a factor of $n$.

Comment: If $\phi(a)=\epsilon$, you can simply remove the symbol $a$ from the input $w$ and apply your TM, isn't it?

Comment: Remove all occurrences of such symbols and *shift* everything to get rid of the holes. This is no easier than expanding the input when some $|\phi(a)|\ge2$,  and likely requires quadratic time on a one-tape machine.

Comment: You are right. But still, if we just add a new letter at any place, it seems that the complexity of the language does not increase. If $w$ has length $n$ and contains $k$ letters $\neq a$, then your MT will take at most $f(k)n/k$, where $f(n)$ is the time complexity of $L$. Assuming $f(k)/k$ is increasing, this gives again f(n)n/n=f(n). Right?

Comment: No, there is no reason to assume that all the gaps have length about $n/k$. It may well be there is a handful of gaps of length $\Omega(n)$, and many gaps of small length. If it so happens that the algorithm spends most of the time crossing back and forth the long gaps, it will take time about $f(k)n$.

Comment: I suspect that $\mathrm{DTIME}_1(n\log n)$ is, in fact, not closed under $\phi^{-1}$ where $\phi(a)=\epsilon$. Although I do not know an explicit counterexample, I think it's too good to be true that every $L\in\mathrm{DTIME}_1(n\log n)$ would be computable by a one-tape TM that crosses each position only $O(\log n)$ times. If $L$ is a counterexample, then $\phi^{-1}(L)$ should require time $\omega(n\log n)$ on inputs where we insert $a^n$ at a position that requires $\omega(\log n)$ crossings.

Comment: Let us consider $L=\{0^nww^{R}: w\in\{a,b\}^{*}, |w|\leq \log n\}$. Then $L\in\textrm{DTIME}_1(n\log n)$. But $0^nw1^nw^R$ should probably require $n(\log n)^2$ time, I guess.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is in $\mathrm{DTIME}_1(n\log n)$. It can be verified by $\log n$ passes over the whole string, each of which deletes every other 0 and 1 (while checking their parity), the first nondeleted symbol of $w$, and the last nondeleted symbol of $w^R$.

Comment: But if you change it to $\{0^nww^R:|w|\le(\log n)^2\}$, I think it should work.